# How can Json be read in ApiController class?

Tags: asp.net, json

I'm trying to read a great amount of data in a POST method. I believe that I have the data but it is encripted and I didn't find how to read the data.

I send data as this:

```
POST /api/SuppliersNotes?tb_suppliers_notes= HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:59663
Authorization: Basic bWNhc3Ryb0BtY3NvZnQuY29tLmJyOjEyMzQ=
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="tb_suppliers_notes"

{ "Supplier_ID": 3, "Date": "2014-05-30T11:22:24.483", "Note": "New information about Tradebook", "Model_ID": null, "Show_Date": "2014-05-30T10:33:24.483", "tb_Suppliers_Notes_Contacts": [ { "Contact_ID": 1 } ] }
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="tb_image"

[{ "Type": "jpg", "Image64": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGAAAABdCAYAAABafGNLAAAABmJLR0QA/wD/AP+gvaeTAAAACXBIWXMAAA7DAAAOwwHHb6hkAAAAB3RJTUUH3gUVDDY7esp+FwAAGjdJREFUeNrtnWuMZdl1139rn+d916u7qx/T0/OI22N72vEzjsGJiUyUxIBQBCgBWRZSSFBwEIrgQxSh8IEIQYRkEQhSgkSkSJEsIkgibCQ7GIODHTKxYSaeyWSm7Z5pd1d3dXe9bt3Xeey9+HDurbq36j6qq6urauIc6Xb1fZ17z157rfVf//1f+wqPcDz93DWNKjXU+P1HBKR/Q0BB97xHD3Li4RfJQd/0mA4Zc9dmJK1N3nj1JTni088+3vdDf0uf//gnOPfdHyEPy7Q7XbIsQ41BTYiTAIuHqhx8wKcZQR7Weo/XAAAGxUeR7habL32Jb/333+TF3/vP8lgN8NGf+Kf67r/9j0mjGlu9hF6WkSVdsm4bm+eoeOQSkrqAxAq5dfzZPgQxQhSGNKplGskab3zmn/PCb/2KHKkBrv7Fj+tHf+4/YuM6zU4bC2AMiGDzhKzTN4ApDJBpYQBrle+EQwGniopHvV6nvv4a/++XPsGtP33xQIYw05788N/9ef3YL/4OHefR2t4G1SK89z9Y+zFe0X1hG/nOuImAZwRfHK3mBivxJd71S3/A1e//6/pIBviBT/0rvfaJX6C5uYE6tzPwE+OwnmyoPg2HEcHYlNWNJhd/9j9x9WM/rocywHv+yif1mb/2D9jeWh+NUTszfuimxW1vXDs1NxGM8RAxx/aZPsrm5joXP/XrXH7P9+lD5YCLzzynP/TLX6XZahGFAUYMDrAoFoM1gjMGRbBZ0k/CGRgPKxE5AakVrDsBPxBBRECKHIU6XJZiO9uI5+GV6/tny+PMD8an7ju++ONnJ+YDf+8D7/+JX+TexhalwNs/+4fDkIwJODLsAnIM423AGEQEVUXzlLzbIW83yVub5O1NbK+D63VYePt7kdoCavPjmw+a0/FqfOAf/aq+8OmflJkGePrah1SufIA87UFQHhln7f+rKqgMJeBBCNL9Iehxz3bba/cHeou8tYnttdE8AxG8IMTEJYL5M/i+R7iwjHX28X+vPQHG9lpUv++TLP/up/Xut16RqQZ49uM/xdrmFo1KPD6VquxWpiMVqjK27H1cl2UMebvJ5h9/GRBMEOJFJaLGIiaMED8ovEMEdY4wDFAvBHf8tYkAnSzl0sc/xd1f/unJHvDMte9Rvfg8ajPQeALQKTygSN26Az912EuG2YjHaADb2iCaWySoL+zG/JGo2P9mLseL5/r54YRqhbTL3Id/DMYYYAcFLV55js1OhoxxUt2buIZgkA5DouPCoM5hO80iqRpv8CXHxkMjYOLK/ms4Vi9Q0rDMk9/9EZ1ogNrld9LL7T7uS/ePOfvHXHcn3eOGomJwSQeX9fD8AFGd+Fqcww8CCGJE3YnC4SzPmL/6ockhKC8t7CK0wX/2Z+F97KSqogoysIDsRUlHPJs8g21vFnDTmOmwUi1+XEWNB86eLGWhlmD52SkG8EsHK2f3GkX3FGP6eFGQqJK1NjFBNPMzBMUr1XB9LzlR6k4g8UqTc0DuZF/IGTf2iuJQHOBGXqfHchUuS7BJBxNGUz9SUTzPR8LSsRZf06aDUzPZA5y6wq1VR4wgOmZ4dfgyR1GpCMjYVH4U6Mcj7awhgPH8/sDKhOhj8ctl1AsRZ4+jMpkxdwQ3rRDTvbB+LNmmKDLCAxUhSAtDPe5SQCDf3sAE4QFClcMvVTntqxL+UJYYIdtGg87kfKBjcrTIY5pveYbttjCl8gQma/dSjGeQuIKo48QTwBRmxkzEm2Nn/xhGtI+CJjDTRxp+bLeFuhzj+QhT4KdagjACP9z3upOFQtNCkII63a0iVXeph2HqWcZnatXBxT+eKlhEyFrrGD/YyVUTX+ssYbWB+BHO5aPx0p1MUJqkLfD3mkd3/o432vj1AEUGA3JUNIQIspNoAXXY9hYmiqaGnwEP0llfJV25ieYZzua4PEPUsfCODyJRGdSdihDkP5wNxxih7yyuH8+OZuwNNunSvPEy6myxIodigpDAD6cHOVUwhl5zHZf0EOMVawG+RxDEeEGIOwFYKrOT8G4FrDo54Q7CUEHM7RJyMvR+4dGysHgG290ma67hl8oIBhMEBOXqgU4rxiOeOzMy7dRaoqjPlDp3/BlBZHoIKgZ0/ODvBKXBWsAUNDTL4gedLS7tUlo6j1euDoWhh5y5OoTNXI4XNgbT45R6wAi/MIXScYqK7BKQez/pUa9QFZd0Ed8fZTcPfd6iejFxqfDXE7DA7Byg/QSs+2f9oDrWIS5IR16jO68xj0zECdgclyWYKEYOCWp1yAOcKp4IXhjjTkizITNh6J44PxnDjlrA9ROwt7caewS4aZMeanNkwPU/BMwTdRgjhUTEeMX/jWBMCfWCIbx8ykKQ7qM1R5nPgWEGJNzgNggZOvASmaH2Oghn0mthBHxTROz8AAoLVcU3wtLyBcT3UYoFe5W+gkOFxOqJrYohs+oAncaATqEidsg7GUoBh0dBqo5yfY6FegUJIpJ2i/X7q4gXTH+fc/h+QDes70hi1OrI7JNpwfhxj7+R6SFoOJzvkzkMgwoZpSEGsGj3LUXUNo/gqrkf06KEiKG9eRtnLZ4fzlh8cfilCopgBr4pBw0EJxeCzD7ExniYuROohiKVjoWvj774IaoFiWYzstbWaEU88UIUL66cEu7/EFwQOiqx1T1q27GV+44hdESgeySqCDHknW3UZnh+dWb8D4IAE5VwnA72cxwMVZlBxg1iOnuXhPd4x+6gj1r2KJnHQvuzVSChGeSbOotfqYLx+4svp9AAB4OhOrGtaKAJGiCdYSJun1LiSCyg5O0mJgxnnkvUEZSrp4RznoaCdDobqjpmuo9DRDqekFM4Gg8QQdOEPOngl2u7TOuEsOp7pq/9cad5/GexoeNXv3ScOwyR24NwNFKFSYHnD30Yj6y7Ac5hPG92+AkjxI+KRCWn0wQi46el2Q9BB4XVHjfYYeF0FwG5IVdwHNlSmIiQbW8ifjD7xc4SlmunduCnz+ZxbCiTCrLBPJcxizJDniNHoE5XS95t4YXRbrvThMMT+vhfT7UNDkTG7Q30e3k11fGrYYPkvPOgPALl2+eCXJ4SRPFUt1ItpIcSxse+wnW4HCAzYCg6KkvcM/AwSSPa54JEdzzgsBYQY7C9dj9Amhnx3xGUKojno6cUfo6gIJ1Jxh2gGtb9SwcjhcMjUvciQt5tIZ4/W3roHH5ceZxS1KP1AJkVgnSI49lLhzJlgX7HcYZ6Nw8zIn0UYJNC+cwM8kwEzCBMHSQBDJZMPQ+cK67zuBLHhM/xH4L73I1QovtalHSIrDt0HSAGrMXlKeKHM2kVYwyeHx0cfPWVFunWGl5U6utL9dg8YFyPwggZt29NeOZ3U8bI6Q6PRwXU5oUKwszgU9UVbUgz6oQRxOQH9NZWuf/iVxBnj391WGaQcftgzk7MH4WoI4zoDhLafdOhyTgR1OUFp2RmnMApxshEnn3fTPMDug/u8uDVrxPVGhjfAzk+2boIB1DGjamGdW8CnmCIwXMyuB3yS+bO7aisZ0RDnDsY9WCCgNadW6y99iLxwhmCIOS41+YPQEWML7xkz/0dM43Q0EPtevIIHRqD/G36Ei+ZIj/0DHmnjbN5UTGPCUPSj/nNm9fZuPEqpaVlgnIV2+sUpfsxW2CmNHEnlOiMqTduz4IDWnzWLBn0FsyEoMaQ5Rm99XvULlzBZumIKxnPx2Ypa3/6NTr371I5dxE/LuGspRSFeL5/rPqIA+iCdHq34/Bgj7Qo7c/eh0ZBCp7v4XnmQIncL1fYvHkdL4wpLZ7rc4SKTRO279xk8+broFC9cBkTBDhrqUQB9eUnSEwA7phzAFMLsckoRifgft2zRPnIS2JSIBXx/ELwO+0cqnhBRFipc++VrxFWanhBhMtS0nYT5xzx3CJRrQHG4PKcajmmdu4JEgn6KOoYY9CB6oC9i/Fjhf97uzL06GhQVcTzCcKINE2LgmmGyxQDH5C2mqSdbYzxiefPEJTKiOehqrg8p1GrUD57kUT9YvA55m11FETt7EqYvQXDUPsR7FkF04ID233sEWFon/+JKhXSpAfiHejKvCimFMVj7KngLIvzDaLF8/ScjHTMyDHGf6eCn3WmGaAYyamk4t7JrqMckDwiCBqcM6rN0dlc5+AaZh1TJigeytLZM0j9DIlVzAnqQq0D09ueXAkPCi6Zok8c3htChzVEe5LwI7m2OiQsUak1cIfcWsZaS8n3OHfhElo/Q2rdoTWmR2WANHHYPJ8OQ/dIbvcMvO7PyOO4IGZyaDMPp0p58Sxpr02SO4wxB36fqGOhXqOydI7EhDjnMCdIlWqf40q3ewTpNA+YlU/3rMhPa2l9ZEEESu6HzC9fJPQMbkZfl1PFWUc58Fk+f57SuUt0Jeh31pzsYQQyC/nGJr00mQZDh2b+3tZ+nVwt7zYIH7GLO0ceVVm6+AStB6u0Or39Pb8KnoFKFFJrNPArcyTiY+0pUkeIkLYyuvfv0kl7U0LQ/r0HxpBy7PDNg51LdiDPzn48RS376Bi76GhMgzK1C09S67VIBnuUKhgjBFFEEJUgKpHi03UO2Qk5J2wCLQjFLBd0bZ27b76CS7amw1AdssBe7npH89OXnBjAeILxDeoMxjNgBDE8mj59hBgqLqSngokb+KUG4ZD8xQI9V6gzBHei6udxsceqwW82WVu9x8bLn2eu5s0qxPYngpGei8HM7+v2B80Prk8Lm74XHLVAbbD3T77ny56aBuxx6VKFSq/DzdUHdFZeJrr/Iix9/+QkPLzthjJll9b+1pCyu4NS//7Q7TEWNKd10HcBAQQiLLked++vs3L/Aeff/F0wHhJEs+hoYaK8XA5w/60wQo9pyiuCMTBvHF7S5pX7He5ttLly/TMseB1MVEXEn24AOUDy0pEdU2RPy5IU3ZNS5IPDVWV6ZGFg+tXIQ7mewFiOzEghDouwSNZjdaPHGx1Dfu8Oz7z4GzwRbCHLT8CN12axof0twMZQ0yKC5xlCA6JCphbrLL4mhOQgFp+ciiaUMyE2OX4uU406biVxsNXwJDx9sIEdcebJZh1icyeZf/CcG0g1ZXemuoGCw1m6WcbtrmU984oi8vUvcuXGF7hyts7Fp76HV7/xYrHIJNOEWUZ2YWX/KNr7PZJOj2yrRbu5TbfVJU1SbG6Lfdh0Fx212F+oTcoJRvbLXSapWeQQYt+pe40PkY5j+0727Bjg+uo/8QUTBGgcouUyLi6RhxHOGKKszZmt65T/5As8E/V48n3XeObqc3z75s3CWOIxVRmHMYgpQosYQyn06K6v883b91lba9FJLFaLVhmDRdShAyr0MMFDH/alR83lyGxP2vOk8Q1+FBI6S6AJld496naDs+kqja038dsPeP797+PMhcucv3CBJOnRbrWK05hZBpAifgeBR0lyvvmN17j7oEMuPlG+xXxvhbp9QMPr0oigEnmEvhD4Pr7v43mm2KXcmAKOniZM/gjFlFPFWktuLdbmCBAZn7ITKr5HEDgy41i48nbece09dDodFhYWqFQq/NELLxTqC3QitT6ShD1PqGK5/uq3aaYeQfceCyv/i2W3wsXFMufPL3P23HnmF5eoN+aoVqvEpTJhGBKEQd8QPp7pF2V/BgygqljrcM5irSVNU5IkpdPtkeY5lVqdSxcvIiLcunWLp556ijAMeeXll/EDvwjHzuGMv5tjxxnAAYuhx+rdTbYzn/KdLzN/87NcOjvHxaefZfHsOepzc9SqNcJyGfyIDIPpQyBnwRnBN4IVr09HmEk5kUGfgfQlgnpquxulmL2ehxglDkvUFkLK5TJRGNLudLizskIQBHzwgx9kdXWV119/nSiO0a2tfg5xOBMUFewkA5QCg6Y5m4lH+e5XOXvzt3nq2aucWb5Ao9GgMTfP3FyDaq1GuVyhVCoRlWKiKCaKIoIgKNzVOcIBN23d2J83GRRsnhhsHBKEIf5BmjFOiMvf5QcdaZrS6/W4t7pKr9ejXq9z7do1giDgpZdeQlWpVCq0tlv91CpkaYrzwrFhaMcA5bzFZg+8ZI0zd3+Py089w8KZs8zNNajXG0RxiLWWbreLUyW3ljTPSNOMJEkIgoAkTemkKfzar7P1yiu0nCXN877YShEE3xhC36caRtTLFdxP/z3Ov/MdhL5/6iNSAcc9Go0Gly9fplKp0Ol0uH79Ouvr6ywvL7O1tYV1bqct0lpLp9OF8Mz0ECTW0bU+c5svsxAr9blFqpUqaZaztbVFQ4Rarc7i4hL1Rp1atUZcLhHHhRcEYUAYxQRhSO+/fp72vQdkRrDO4dQN+jYQMXjGEPl+oX5417s489zbT3EIGoWnaZrS6XS4ffs2Dx48QFU5c+YMly5dYmVlhfn5eba3t4uO/zwnSRLanTau+k6EKQZIsgJWlru3qTfmiaKIVrtNvV6jXq9TKpVI04TVe6usb6wThCFRFBGGEUEYEgQ+fhBggojLaY9SOSbcJ35S2BFeCYnLee3111hxFs2yt0ReFhF836dcLvPkk08W4ejePXzf5/z589y9e5dyucz29jbWWtbX1+mmFnfmCuT3JhsgtYWCoOxlhFFEkiTMz88RBAGtVovMWubm5pir1qhWa5QrZeJSTBSVChQUBARhWAigNKeddEDDfXBah1a9EmtZXFxg8dw51Nq3hAEGOWBzc5MkSahWq1y8eJH19XVWV1dZWlpi9e4qnuex9mCN1uYGXa+KnXsKuXtzsgEGO4x4XoBql1Ick6QpCiwuLjE3N0e5XGyY2ku6WHVkWU4SZYRRSBCEBQyNIoJeG3otcOEUbFEYoN1qE7ZauLeABxS/yGSI45h6vU6e56ytrXHz5k0WFxcJgoD79+9TrVV5/bXXWFt7QLe1xXr5CsHcOaLrq1MM0FyBxffiogah36bb61Kt1ahWqlhn2dzcKixeq1GtVotiyxRfyIjpb5BU/O0kXVyvhWg0+WJUSfooqWhweWvUDL1ej62tLbIsIwxD5ufnaTQarKysEMcx8/Pz3Lhxg431ddbXHtCzcHfu3ZytRriNKR6Q3noR810/SjteJu3coFFfxIhhu7VNpVpjaalReEGlQhhFRHFMHMVEcdSHoQWc9KKIlk1JknZ/zWpykZM6y0IcU6vVcPlbJwcYY8jznGazyZ07dwjDkAsXLrC+tsbKygrNrS3u3LmDS9rcMhdIFt/OknT4mZ/9ST7xd/7HeAPc+uMvydMf7elm/CQ2+b8kSRcxhvmFecqlEmmasr6xQbvdIS6XdgwQRtFODvCDAC+MaHXbxS8xTZOXq5I6x9r6GtxbfUuEICg0R4PdWarVKpcvX6bZbHLr1i1Ula3NTW7fvkWvvU0rhZfL7+fc4jz27kt84uc/Of1XlNz1z5M88yPc7z1FObuBlKt02h2cKo3GHNVKhXqjURRi5RJxqTRqhDDEjyJeNdBNu0yT84g6Uqc8cfYsFy9dwuX5W8IAzjnyPKfT6dBsNrl//z6e5yEi3L59m3urq7S2t9GswwvubSRnn+NC1ePOFz43mwt647/9a7nyD39Yb5bfx3JrBdNp4fkNjCm0Oa1WizTLieI2cRztVsFhSBiG+EGAH8V0ej2ss1OVbaKOXJV7q6u4+VvoW8gABVjx8Dwf38tZW19nc3ODrc0ttptNJG3zh81FXqt/L+84WyHffsCb//szs3/IDcC8+l/Yftvf5M36h3ln9/fJ0ox2u1MUUkYIwqhYjO9vB+z32VDf9/EDnyAMClp7aFnSGyzAKFh25S0K+EFAHMfYND31sX8w+7Mso9Vq0e12d2Bpa7tFq7mFSVt89X7EH5Q+wsXlJc7UQ17/zH+YeN59BvjW5/+dPHn+fXq9cpVKucvb8m+gLuzzIBntTpvc5vSShCgsEvAODA0C/LiE74dUSjWCOMZXZS3LWVcoGeGMMRgjpKr4fa9a39jAnXID7CzgWId1dscQ3U6H7e0mWWebXrvJZ9/weaH0YZaWL/H2SxXe/MYfcfvLv3nw35IE2P6fn6b2I/+Cb5hrRLUyV+3LYDOstThrcc4VFKv2b06Lx1Rx6qhV5qjNneW2Uz7nhM1nn6J09hxJs4l/6yZ/odfmmm9oOWXzIfYGPcmBHwx+lmdkaUqSJCS9LjbpYrvbvPTmGp9bned2/b1cWF7i+aer3H2wya/9jSt89N/AQxlg/Y2XhM/9nNY+/i/5P91n2S7V+FB8g7KfEQWGOPSJIp8oDoijkCgK+3kgwI9Dnphb4Gu1NX67Mcd7//IP8oFrz1OOS3S7XV6+fp2vfOUrpGsP+Fivh6mUqFdLuOwUGkILKtnmOVmakdgMm3chS3DdDuvrTV661eT37/i8yrsJlq/w/IUKl55ocGejw+1f/ft89J98/WEW3UaPhcvv0NoP/jPScJ7lOOG50irl5A6xp8SlMnGpXBBx/TrAD4pk3PnSF3kxili+fIWr33V1ZwZJv2j79s03uLPxgKubTbwnr1C68jScQipCVYuFmLxgfNvtLvebLW6vd7mxYbnRjtjwFonnz/HE2RqXlyNozLH65hus/vuf4v43XzqQdmDmcfGv/oLK5Y+gLqdMB5Nu0Ops08ksqfo4ExQbq3oBGB8X+ISm2L3W7WxlZnZ+kMPzDDhL7gdIlnFEWsbHuiYz6KFV42H8gFIcM1crsVAPqdUDtFKhqQGbX/4tXv+Vn5GHOvVBjsW3fa+W3vNjmKXn8Hyf2Fgiz+GbQVe77KCFXdmcHuajTrctjCCeQUIfLZex1RqpH5J862tsfvbfcvfrX5SHtu3DHPOX36nhEx/Av3ANr34JgtKepbZJDVgyM96O3JUpr5Mp75/53PQtMGcJCcQI4ntIIEi6Rn7763Rf/iIP/uQP5dDO9ajHX/rhH913RW98+xYAm1vb/TGQh/toMXt7X/tFhQ/W7vkdgP66LQr7OhENGL+fUftViPHHDLT0dU75vu+6757L2br1yneS+PLPjz8/HtPx/wFjz5627fvWJAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" }]
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
```

This method received the data

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostSuppliersNotes(NameValueCollection tb_suppliers_notes)
{
  string xx = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

But xx value is this:

```
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"  }]
------WebKitFormBoundaryWCoudRJAvagjb7cQ--
```

The question is: how do I read xx data as the data was when sent from the service consumer?

I have tried to read data from parameter tb_suppliers_notes but the data is allways Null. I tried [FromBody] sending data as RAW with no success. All I got was read Headers but there is a data size limit.

Thanks,
Marco Castro

Comment: Try modifying your read to ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NakedBody] described in http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Dec/13/Accepting-Raw-Request-Body-Content-with-ASPNET-Web-API solves the problem.

With this article you can receive the Json string as method parameter and with this code

var converted = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(stringParameter);

You translate Json to Dot.Net and do the job.